# Mongodb C# driver update issue

Tags: c#, mongodb

Before driver 2.0 I was able to create the update statement based on different business logic like

```
   var update = new UpdateBuilder();
   update.set("FN","Devesh")
   if(true)
       update.set("MN","kumar")
```

Since I have upgraded to version 2 the similar approach like this

```
   var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update;
   var updateQuery = update.Set("FN", "Devesh");
   if(true)
       updateQuery.set("MN","kumar")
```

Now only updates the "FN" and not the "MN". Seems like it is not updating the same object. Any idea how to achieve the same.

I am using C# official driver.

**UPDATE**

```
   var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update;
   var updateQuery = update.Set("FN", "Devesh");
   if(true)
       updateQuery = updateQuery.set("MN","kumar")
```

Works as expected but it seems to be too ugly and prone to error. Can we achieve it in much better way ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be a more manageable solution for you

```
var updateList = new List<UpdateDefinition<TProduct>>();

updateList.Add(Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("FN", "Devesh"));

if (true)
{
    updateList.Add(Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("MN", "kumar"));
}

var combinedUpdates = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Combine(updateList);
```

After which you can use the combinedUpdates as your regular updateDefinition.